# Is sulfur a "miracle cure"?

Tags: medical-science, natural-remedies, nutritional-supplements

There are claims that sulfur and its compounds like organic sulfur and MSM can cure many health issues.

Sulfur and [Methylsulfonylmethane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methylsulfonylmethane) or MSM for short is being claimed to have these benefits:

> - Increasing enzyme production within bodily glands and improving resistance to illness
> - Increasing flexibility in muscle tissue
> - Increasing blood circulation
> - Reducing muscle inflammation and promoting muscle healing
> - Promoting the healthy growth of hair and fingernails
> - Discouraging the growth of cancer cells through oxygenation
> - Reversing osteoporosis, Alzheimer's disease and Parkinson's disease
> - Promoting healthy skin production and reducing wrinkles
> - Regulating insulin production
> - Improving colon function and eliminating colonic parasites

from http://www.naturalnews.com/029263_sulfur_joint_health.html

More claims about its various "miracle" properties:

- http://articles.mercola.com/sites/articles/archive/2011/09/12/the-third-abundant-mineral-in-your-body-are-you-getting-enough.aspx
- http://www.msm-info.com/msm_brochure_pdf.pdf
- http://www.healthy.net/scr/article.aspx?ID=2066
- http://www.naturalnews.com/037292_msm_sulfur_breast_cancer.html

What does sulfur actually help with?

Does it make sense to take MSM supplements?

How much of a miracle cure is it in reality?

Comment: In general anything claiming to be a miracle cure for every single (completely unrelated) illness should be a gigantic red flag...

Comment: I've changed your question to be answerable on this site: a) I've reduced it to one claim (benefits of sulfur); b) removed secondary claims (effects of sulfur deficiency, conspiracy theories about bigpharma); c) made it more balanced removing bias words like "conspiracy", etc.; d) used a real claim instead of a possibly incorrect syntesis.

Comment: @nico thats what I thought too, but some of it actually makes some sense, for example that it helps nails and hair because keratin has lots of sulfur and so do blood vessel cell bonds, many hormones and enzymes.

Comment: @TimoHuovinen: sure, but between a possible benefit in certain particular situations and a general "cure-it-all" medicine there is a lot of room!